# Question regarding Limsup of a sequence of sets and its measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right) $
  be a measure space and suppose  $\left\{ A_{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty} $
  is a sequence of sets such that  $\mu\left(A_{n}\right)\geq\varepsilon $
  for some  $\varepsilon>0$
  and for all  $n\in\mathbb{N}$
 . Is this contradictory to $\mu\left(\limsup\limits _{n\to\infty}A_{n}\right)=0$
  ?

I've come accustomed to thinking of Limsup as the set of $x\in X$
  that belong to $A_{n}$
  for an infinite number of $n$. With that in mind I don't really see any reason why this should be acontradiction. Using the more formal definition of $${\displaystyle \limsup_{n\to\infty}A_{n}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k\geq n}A_{k}}$$
  also doesn't seem to provide an obvious contradiction.
Also ,does it make any difference if the measure was a finite measure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using the more formal definition of limsup ... also doesn't seem to provide an obvious contradiction.

Well, it does. Note first that for every $n$,
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{k\geqslant n}A_k\right)\geqslant\mu(A_n)\geqslant\varepsilon,
$$
and deduce from this that
$$
\mu\left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n\right)\geqslant\varepsilon,
$$
under the dominating condition that
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}A_n\right)
$$
is finite. This condition is always satisfied when the measure $\mu$ is finite.

Recall that the measure of the union of a nondecreasing sequence of measurable sets is always the limit of the measures of the sets but that the measure of the intersection of a nonincreasing sequence of measurable sets is guaranteed to be the limit of the measures of the sets only when one of the sets has finite measure. A counterexample to keep in mind: $A_n=[n,+\infty)$ in $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ with the Lebesgue measure. Or, equivalently, $A_n=\{k\in\mathbb N\mid k\geqslant n\}$ in $(\mathbb N,2^\mathbb N)$ with the counting measure.

Comment: $A_n = [n,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Unless you have a condition $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty A_n\right) < \infty$$ for some $k$, there is no contradiction.

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course, shame on me... Thanks.

Comment: I had a feeling that the measure being finite is sufficient for this being true. Thanks Did and Daniel.